# Assigning an Array-like to a Array-of-Array

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm relatively new to Javascript and Angular and am trying to understand Javascript's Array and Array-like 'types'.

I have some code that calls a (Java) API that returns a map of data objects:

```
Map<Integer, Data> dataMap;
```

In the Angular code, the response body is mapped to:

```
data: Data[][]
```

In my mainly-Java-thinking mind this would mapped as:

```
[ [Data()], .... , [Data()] ]
```

i.e. a Java array-of-arrays

However what I actually see (via a debugger) is a Javascript Array-like object:

```
{ 1: Data(), .... , n: Data() }
```

This in itself is not a problem for me and actually something I would like to utilise but how has the Array-like object been assigned to the Array type, i.e. how has:

`data: Data[][] = {1: Data, ... , n: Data}`

managed to happen? (because I can't write any code to do it, but I would like to achieve that else where in my code - reason being is that in the map returned from the API, the key begins at 1, not 0.

Comment: use JSON.stringify to check the structure

Comment: How do you fill the structure in JavaScript?

Comment: Do you use Map from JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: `const data:any[][]=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]` or `const data:any[][]=[[{prop1:1},{prop1:2}],[{prop1:1},{prop1:2}]]`

Comment: @SharikovVladislav: I haven't filled the data structure - it's what the Angular HTTP methods have provided me.

Comment: Do your client and server communicate via json? Can you provide some simplified example?

Comment: @Eliseo: While I assume that would work, I have a typed array of Data[][]. I cannot and don't want to remove the type.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's HttpClient actually doesn't convert the response to the type you give to it, it just declares the type of the response. So assuming the API returns a JSON, the javascript object that `http.get<T>(...)` produces will have the same structure, no matter what type `T` is.

If you want it to produce `Data[][]`, you need to do the conversion manually. I haven't seen your code for the http request, but it should look something like this:

```
type DataMap = {[id: number]: Data}
const dataobjects = this.http.get<DataMap>('/api/...').pipe(
    map(response => {
        const arrayResponse = [];
        for(const i in response) {
            arrayResponse.push([response[i]]);
        }
        return arrayResponse;
    }));
```

Now, `dataobjects` is an Observable that emits a `Data[][]` (where each element in the outer array is an array with only one `Data` element).

Comment: ok, but I'd like to know how Angular has managed to assign an Array-like to an Array .. these are different 'types'?

Comment: In what way do you mean it has assigned it to an Array? Can you show the code where you do the request?

Comment: I'll provide a simplified example shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Map equivalent in type script is something like this:

```
  arrayOfArrayMap: { [key: number]: Data[] } = {};
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.arrayOfArrayMap[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        this.arrayOfArrayMap[i].push(new Data());
      }
    }
    console.log(this.arrayOfArrayMap);
  }
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gxn7n

Comment: `arrayOfArrayMap`  has been declared as an object? What I declare is `Data[][]` but in the debugger it appears as an Array-like object.

Comment: do a console log in each line that you do this.data = somervar. . Typescript is typed but when u transpile TS convert it to a vanilla js. and you dont have types and you do something like this: this.data = this.httpService.getApiData() and your getApiData method return a object. you are asing a object to your var dont matter the type because in runtime dont exist types.